# Continuous maps on compact topological spaces which induce compact (Fredholm) operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. A continuous  map $f:X \to X$ defines a bounded linear operator $T_{f}$ on the Banach space $C(X)=\{\phi:X\to \mathbb{C} \mid \phi\; \text{is continuous}\}$  with $T_{f}(\phi)=\phi \circ f$.

Put $X=[0,1]$.

> What is  an example of  a non constant map $f$ such that $T_{f}$ is  a compact operator?
>   What is  an example of  a map $f$ such that $T_{f}$ is  a Fredholm operator of non-zero index?

For  a  linked MSE  question [see this  MSE  post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373804/non-injective-continuous-maps/1373823#1373823).

Comment: It is easy to check that $T_f$ is compact iff it has finite rank iff $f[X}$ is a finite set.  For the not completely obvious implication, compose $T_f$ with the restriction mapping $R$ from $C(X)$ to $C(f[X])$.  The composition $RT_f$ is a quotient map by Tietze, and $C(f[X])$ is infinite dimensional if $f[X}$ is infinite. In particular, if $X$ is connected then $T_f$ is not compact unless $f$ is constant.  As for your second question, let $X$ be the range of a sequence of distinct points together with its limit and let $f$ act as a shift.

Comment: @BillJohnson  Prof.  Johnson Thank you for your very interesting comment. My second question is about X=interval.

Comment: The only way for $T_f$ to be Fredholm when $X=[0,1]$ is for it to be a surjective homeomorphism.  If $f$ is not surjective, then $T_f(\phi)=0$ when every $\phi$ is supported off of the interval $f[0,1]$.  If $f$ is not $1-1$, then there are infinitely many pairs $(a,b)$ of distinct points s.t. $f(a)=f(b)$, which implies that $T_f$ cannot have finite codimensional range.

Comment: @BillJohnson  Does this 1-1 argument works if we replace the interval by a compact  manifold M? If yes, we would obtain an alternative proof for the fact that the spase of homeomorphisms of a compact manifold is  an open set(As it is proved in Hircsh Diff. topology). This would be  a consequence of openness of fredholm operatores. So is it obvious that for a non 1-1 map f on M there are infinite pairs (a,b) with f(a)=f(b)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image of $f$ is an interval $[a,b] \subset [0,1]$.

$T_f$ induce an isometric inclusion of $C([a,b])$ in $C([0,1])$.

If $T_f$ was compact then weak convergence of a bounded sequence in $C([a,b])$ would imply norm convergence in $C([0,1])$ which would in turn (as $T_f$ is isometric) imply norm convergence in $C([a,b])$. which is only possible if $C([a,b])$ is finite dimensional i.e. if $f$ is constant.

(edit: $C([a,b])$ is embeded in $C([0,1])$ by extending the functions by their value on the boundary outside $[a,b]$ and I'm identifying $T_f$ with its restriction to $C([a,b])$, which is also compact...)